# Powershell equivalent of ".Single()" For a C#/Java programmer

Tags: linq, powershell

I'm writing some scripts for my CI, and I've noticed that I'm not doing a good job of asserting on the uniqueness of my filters. For example, one script assumes that

```
$availableZip = $(Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter "*SomeName*.zip" -Recurse).FullName
```

will provide a unique entry, but it may provide no entries or it may provide multiple entries.

This can of course be handled down-stream with some If-Else checking, but what I'd like to do is elegantly push PowerShell to generate an error for me, with something like

```
$availableZip = $(Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter "*SomeName*.zip" -Recurse | Where -Single).FullName
```

such that `Where -Single` would throw some kind of `SetIsEmptyException` or `SetContainsMultipleElementsException`, with all the PowerShell accoutrements pointing specifically to this line and maybe even including the duplicate members.

> Where-Object : value contains multiple elements where only one is allowed, 
>   available elements: firstDirectory\SomeSoftware.zip, Another-SomeSoftware.zip
>   at C:\Users\geoff\Code\Project\MyScript.ps1:33 char:73
>   + ...ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter "*SomeSoftware*.zip" -recurse | Where -Single).FullName
>   + ~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], SingletonSetContainsMultipleElementsException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TooManyElements,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Is there a built-in way for me to do this? Is there some PowerShell trick I can employ, or should I use a little module with a private function (and, if so, whats the most elegant implementation?)

Comment: Best practice says that if you expect certain outcomes (e.g. no entry or multiple entries), you should test for them instead of treating them as exceptions. I know it does not solve your problem, but the fact that you are having to find a workaround is an indication that perhaps you are attempting something that is not quite right.

Comment: `@(Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter "*SomeName*.zip" -Recurse)` _always_ returns an array; checking its `.Count` property could answer your question (a unique entry => `1`, no entries => `0`or it may provide multiple entries => a number greater than `1`).

Comment: "you should test for them instead of treating them as exceptions." I'm not skilled enough to do this, I'm just looking to add a kind of post-condition cheaply.

Answer (score 3):

You could always just use Linq like below. I tried to make it more efficient by only getting the names of the zip folders at first.

```
[string[]]$zips = @(Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter "*SomeName*.zip" -Recurse -Name)

[string]$availableZipName = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Single($zips)

$availableZip = Get-ChildItem -Path $availableZipName -Recurse
```

Below I have put it into a function for ease of use.

```
function Get-AvailableZip (
    [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ })]
    [string]$Path,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Filter
)
{
    [string[]]$zips = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Filter -Recurse -Name);

    [string]$availableZipName

    $availableZip = $null

    try
    {
            $availableZipName = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Single($zips)

            $availableZip = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path\$availableZipName" -Recurse
    }
    catch [System.InvalidOperationException]
    {


        if ($_.Exception.Message -eq "Sequence contains more than one element")
        {
            Write-Error -Message ([Environment]::NewLine + $_.Exception.Message + [Environment]::NewLine + "Files Found:" + [Environment]::NewLine + [string]::Join([Environment]::NewLine, $zips)) -Category LimitsExceeded -Exception ($_.Exception)            
        }
        else
        {
            if ($_.Exception.Message -eq "Sequence contains no elements")
            {
                Write-Error -Message ([Environment]::NewLine + $_.Exception.Message) -Category ObjectNotFound -Exception ($_.Exception)
            }
            else
            {
                throw
            }
        }
    }

    return $availableZip;
}
```

Usage:

```
Get-AvailableZip -Path ".\" -Filter "*SomeName*.zip"
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot find an overload for "Single" and the argument count: "1"`

Comment: @Groostav I added in something that fixed that. It was because $zips was null if there were none.

Comment: I also updated the function to show your custom errors.@Groostav

Answer (score 2):

If you want to A. use the Pipeline, B. have something reusable and C. have something reasonably fast:

```
  function Where-SingleObject {
    param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, HelpMessage='Data to process')]$InputObject
    )
    begin {
      $i = 0
    }
    process {
      if($i -eq 1) {
        throw "Error"
      }; $i++
    }
    end {
      return $InputObject
    }

  }

  (Get-ChildItem -Path '' -Filter '' -Recurse).FullName | Where-SingleObject
```

You can remove `Mandatory` and add a custom Error for 0, if you would like.